# PyQt error “QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running”

Tags: python, pyqt

When I try to run the following PyQt code for running processes and tmux, I encounter the error `QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.` How can I fix this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class embeddedTerminal(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self._processes = []
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.terminal = QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.terminal)
        self._start_process(
            'xterm',
            ['-into', str(self.terminal.winId()),
             '-e', 'tmux', 'new', '-s', 'my_session']
        )
        button = QPushButton('list files')
        layout.addWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self._list_files)

    def _start_process(self, prog, args):
        child = QProcess()
        self._processes.append(child)
        child.start(prog, args)

    def _list_files(self):
        self._start_process(
            'tmux', ['send-keys', '-t', 'my_session:0', 'ls', 'Enter']
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = embeddedTerminal()
    main.show()
```

Comment: Which bit causes the error, just running, or clicking the button? I imagine you need to change `child` to `self.child` to prevent garbage collection of `child` as soon as the function ends.

Answer (score 3):

You usually get the error `QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running` when the application closes and the process hadn't finished.

In your current code, your application ends at soon as it starts, because you didn't call `app.exec_()`. You should do something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = embeddedTerminal()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, it works fine, but when you close the application you will still get the error message. You need to overwrite the close event to end the process properly. This works, given you replace `child` by `self.child`:

```
def closeEvent(self,event):
    self.child.terminate()
    self.child.waitForFinished()
    event.accept()
```